# How Can I Interact With <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have

```
<select>
  <option value="longSleeve">Long Sleeve</option>
  <option value="shortSleeve">Short Sleeve</option>
</select>
```

how can I make my code do something when one is pressed.
For example how can I make a variable set to 1 when 'Long Sleeve' is chosen and set the variable to 2 when 'Short Sleeve' is chosen and then if 'Long Sleeve' is chosen again set it back to 1.

Also pardon my noobyness at coding

Comment: with jquery you have the event change $('select').change(function(){//do something});

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `onchange` event handler, in `jQuery` you can use `.change()` or `.on('change', handler)` like this:

```
var someVariable;
$('select').on('change', function(){
     someVariable = this.selectedIndex + 1;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can always add listeners like

```
.click()
```

to any tag on your html code, maybe you can add an id to that tag

```
<option id="firstOption" value="longSleeve">Long Sleeve</option>
```

and have something like

```
$("#firstOption").click(function(){
   alert("click First option!");
});
```

hope this help : )

[link to jquery reference...](http://api.jquery.com/click/)